# Windows 10 Inconsistent Button Appearance

Tags: windows-10, gui

On Windows 10, the buttons with visual styles take the appearance of a light-gray rectangle and a darker border. When hovered, the background and border turn blue: [image: Normal left, hovered right]

In some programs, there is a fade between colors. In others, the color will change immediately. Now I wonder, why is this the case? I suspect perhaps that the programs that don't replicate that transition aren't actually using the builtin buttons, but rather mimicking them.

Comment: While they may look similar, this means they are different controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite visual similarities, these different buttons are made using different bits of code, different controls, and this is the primary reason for the subtle difference between them.